# For every $x\in[\frac{3}{2}, 5]$ prove that: $(\sqrt{2x-3}+\sqrt{15-3x}+2\sqrt{x+1})^2<71.25$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, problem-solving, intuition, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

For every $x\in[\frac{3}{2}, 5]$ prove that: $(\sqrt{2x-3}+\sqrt{15-3x}+2\sqrt{x+1})^2<71.25$

I proved this by saying that $(\sqrt{2x-3}+\sqrt{15-3x}+2\sqrt{x+1})^2=(\sqrt{2}*\sqrt{x-\frac{3}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}*\sqrt{10-2x}+2\sqrt{x+1})^2$

$\le [(\sqrt{2})^2+(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}})^2+2^2][(\sqrt{x-\frac{3}{2}})^2+(\sqrt{10-2x})^2+(\sqrt{x+1})^2$ (B.C.S)

$=71.25$

It took me too long till I used $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}, 2$ as the numbers for the second bracket used in BCS. Could you please explain to me why I should have immediately intuitively thought of using them and not any other set of numbers?

Comment: Notice that the numbers are so random to be thought of. When you meet similar problems that require you to balance the coefficients, try to set those coefficients as variables first, then expand the expressions and determine which value of coefficients will make your problem look easier to solve. See the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll choose positives $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ such that after using C-S we'll get:$$\left(\sqrt{2x-3}+\sqrt{15-3x}+2\sqrt{x+1}\right)^2=$$
$$=\left(\sqrt{\alpha}\sqrt{\frac{2x-3}{\alpha}}+\sqrt{\beta}\sqrt{\frac{15-3x}{\beta}}+\sqrt{\gamma}\sqrt{\frac{4x+4}{\gamma}}\right)^2\leq$$
$$\leq(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)\left(\frac{2x-3}{\alpha}+\frac{15-3x}{\beta}+\frac{4x+4}{\gamma}\right)=71.25,$$
For which we need: $$\frac{2}{\alpha}-\frac{3}{\beta}+\frac{4}{\gamma}=0$$ and
$$(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)\left(\frac{-3}{\alpha}+\frac{15}{\beta}+\frac{4}{\gamma}\right)=\frac{285}{4}.$$
The first gives $$\beta=\frac{3\alpha\gamma}{2(2\alpha+\gamma)}$$ and we obtain:
$$\left(\alpha+\frac{3\alpha\gamma}{2(2\alpha+\gamma)}+\gamma\right)\left(\frac{-3}{\alpha}+\frac{15}{\frac{3\alpha\gamma}{2(2\alpha+\gamma)}}+\frac{4}{\gamma}\right)=\frac{285}{4}$$ or
$$(2\alpha-\gamma)(96\alpha^2+7\alpha\gamma-28\gamma^2)=0$$ and we can choose $$\gamma=2\alpha,$$ which gives $$\beta=\frac{3}{4}\alpha$$ and for $\alpha=2$ we obtain your solution.

Easy to see that $71.25$ is not a maximal value.

Indeed, the equality should be occur for
$$(\sqrt{\alpha},\sqrt{\beta},\sqrt{\gamma})||\left(\sqrt{\frac{2x-3}{\alpha}},\sqrt{\frac{15-3x}{\beta}},\sqrt{\frac{4x+4}{\gamma}}\right),$$
which gives $$\frac{\sqrt{2x-3}}{\alpha}=\frac{\sqrt{15-3x}}{\beta}=\frac{\sqrt{4x+4}}{\gamma}$$ or
$$\frac{\sqrt{2x-3}}{\alpha}=\frac{\sqrt{15-3x}}{\frac{3}{4}\alpha}=\frac{\sqrt{4x+4}}{2\alpha}.$$
From the first and the third fractions we obtain $x=4$, which not so plays with the second fraction.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Rozenberg, it is always a pleasure hearing from you. Have a good day